# Display date with JavaScript in a specific html tag

Tags: javascript, html

I have this simple Java Script code to display the date.
I want to take the results from the js, and to show them within a specific html in the document. Example; div, p, h3, etc.
If I place the script in the  tag, it will overwrite my existing html page.
How can I display the date in a specific tag within the html page?

```
<script language="JavaScript">
<!--
var current_date = new Date ( );

var month_names = new Array ( );
month_names[month_names.length] = "January";
month_names[month_names.length] = "February";
month_names[month_names.length] = "March";
month_names[month_names.length] = "April";
month_names[month_names.length] = "May";
month_names[month_names.length] = "June";
month_names[month_names.length] = "July";
month_names[month_names.length] = "August";
month_names[month_names.length] = "September";
month_names[month_names.length] = "October";
month_names[month_names.length] = "November";
month_names[month_names.length] = "December";

document.write ( month_names[current_date.getMonth()] );
document.write ( " " + current_date.getDate() );
document.write ( " " );
document.write ( " " + current_date.getFullYear() );
// -->
</script>
```

Comment: For declaring the array don't have to do all that month_mans.length mess. You could simply do

   `var month_names = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];`

and you would get the exact same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var months = [ //create the months
    'January',
    'February',
    'March',
    'April',
    'May',
    'June',
    'July',
    'August',
    'September',
    'October',
    'November',
    'December'
], d, m, y, now, out_string; //vars to hold date, month, year, date object and output string
now = new Date(); //new date object
d = now.getDate(); //current date
m = now.getMonth(); // current month
y = now.getFullYear(); //current year


out_string = months[m] + ' ' + d + ' , ' + y; //concat date parts into output string 

document.getElementById('yourIDHere').innerHTML = out_string; //set the html of the hmtl element to the output string
```

http://jsfiddle.net/22MVm/1/

Comment: I think your solution is a bit easier for a beginner to understand, but rather than just hand out the code, it would probably be beneficial to add some comments on why you did some of the stuff you did?

Comment: @mcmullins Thanks for the tip on my response. I have updated the code above but left the fiddle alone.

Comment: As a beginner i find this a little eaiser to understand, I still have an issue get the date to appear in my html page. I am not sure why it does not execute in the date div id i created.

Comment: You should put your version of the date js and HTML into jsfiddle that way everyone can see exactly what you are doing and help guide you in the right direction. http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 3):

You almost never use `document.write` for the reason you mentioned. That is, if applied after the page has finished rendering, it will overwrite the existing page.

just do

```
document.getElementById('id-of-element-to-write-into').innerHTML = 
    month_names[current_date.getMonth()] +
    " " + current_date.getDate() +
    " " + current_date.getFullYear()
```

Instead of `document.getElementById`, you can also use

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByTagName (safest for cross-browser)
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.querySelector
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByClassName

or just

Comment: There are perfectly good times when you should use document.write().

Comment: @j08961 Please elaborate, in which case should you use `document.write` instead of DOM manipulation? It goes against separation between JS and HTML, it makes your function unusable unless the script tag is placed in a specific part of the document. Never heard of anyone advocating for document.write

Comment: One case is optionally including scripts in your html depending on the existence of an online copy...ex: with only including a local copy of jQuery if the online copy isn't reachable. An example of this in use can be seen in the h5bp template [here](https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/index.html#L51).

Comment: I'm not going to start a debate in the comments about the use of document.write(). All I'm saying is that there are perfectly legitimate situations to use it and "don't ever use" is not advice to follow.

Comment: @mcmullins @j08691 Changed my broad statement about `document.write`. In mcmullin's example, that could easily be done with DOM manipulation (maybe not as easily as `document.write`, see the example where it loads the google analytics script). The case that I know of is when you import a script (say a twitter feed) that is going to write HTML on the page. In that case, I prefer to pass the id of the node to write into to the script and the script can use DOM manipulation instead